# Cropping a upload preview with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a image preview when a user adds a image.

The js looks like this:

```
       function logoImg(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#logo_img_prev')
          .attr('src', e.target.result)
          .width(210)
          .height(165);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
```

This works great for displaying the image.  But I want the image to crop to those dimensions and not resize the photo.  What jquery can I use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is your answer.

You need to set the image up as a background and use `background-size: cover`. This would scale the photo down to it's smallest size possible and keep ratio.

Use an element like `<div>`:

```
<div id="logo_img_prev">
</div>
```

You JS should be:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
  $('#logo_img_prev')
      .css({
          'background-image': 'url(' + e.target.result + ')',
          'background-size': 'contain',
          'width': '210px',
          'height': '165px'
      });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution.  You're code is previewing a broken image though.